# Example of projective Calabi-Yau as branched covering of flag manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

I couldn't find in the litterature some example of a projective Calabi Yau manfiold, which would be realized as a branched (ramified) covering of a flag manifold other than the projective space.

Could you show me an example or a reference suggesting the existence of such a situation ?

Comment: There are plenty: the anticanonical bundle $K_F^{-1}$ of a flag manifold $F$ is very ample, take a smooth divisor $B$ in the linear system $|K_F^{-2}|$ and the double cover of $F$ branched along $B$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Are these examples smooth?

Comment: Yes, of course, since $B$ is smooth.